# Is there something like incomplete (partial) declarations for Flow?

Tags: javascript, declaration, flowtype

I'd like to incrementally add declarations for external library. Is it possible to write a declaration that describes only certain properties of an object/interface and remaining properties are omitted from declaration and thus unchecked?

For example: Can following object

```
const a = {foo: 8, bar: 9}
```

have declaration describing only one property?

```
declare var a: any|{foo: number} // doesn't actually work
```

The intended behavior is that if a property is found in the declaration then the type is enforced. Type of all non-mentioned properties is considered to be `any`.

---

Typescript solves this problem using extra properties expression:

```
interface Iface {
    foo: number;
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: `{foo: number}&Object` maybe?

Comment: `{ foo: number, [key: string]: any }` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type PartialA = {foo:number, [key:string]: any}
const a: PartialA = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
console.log(a.bar)
```

This options is safer than following one since types of known properties are onforced:

```
a.foo = 'a' // causes error
// 6: a.foo = 'a'
//            ^ string. This type is incompatible with
// 3: type PartialA = {foo:number, [key:string]: any}
//                         ^ number
```

or

```
type PartialB = {foo:number}&any
const b: PartialB = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
console.log(b.bar)
b.foo = 'a' // Ok in Flow
```

Tested with Flow v0.34.0

Credit: [@loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth), [@gcanti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6629088/gcanti)

Comment: `{foo: number} & Object` or `{ foo: number } & any` are unsafe: you can write `b.foo = 'a'` and typechecks